# run executable code that accept input parameter and produce output, in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have written a jquery/javascript editor in FLEX 3 and actionscript 3. It has syntax checking facility. I will write a syntax checking parser either in C or in java. Here, I will include executable file only with flex code. That executable file should accept fully qualified file name as input parameter and it produce compilation result as output, that i need to display in flex.

Please anybody provide suitable solution that how to add executable file in flex, that will accept input parameter and produce output.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can send parameters via NativeProcess in AIR 2 to a console application for example

lee brimelow has nice two part tutorial here's the part2 link that you will need:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=126

to receive data you can use the standarOutPutData Event

documentation : 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html#event:standardOutputData

Comment: ok thanks a lot. but how can i receive output from executable file, in flex ?